# Access localhost on VirtualBox IIS

Tags: iis, networking, virtual-machine

I am hosting a virtual machine (Windows 7) on my machine via VirtualBox. I am using a bridged connection to my host laptop. I am attempting to access `localhost` on the VM from another machine on the network. When I use `ipconfig` from my host machine I get:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9538:86c4:59e3:a43f%23
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

When I try to access `192.168.56.1`, I am unable to load the page. I can ping `192.168.56.1` and get a reply, but I am not sure if this is the correct IP address to use.

I have also attempted to use the IP address from my guest machine (VM)

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9538:86c4:59e3:a43f%23
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.24
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.1
```

but I am unable to get a reply when ping the `192.168.2.24` from my host. Any suggestions here?

Comment: do you have IIS running ? and when you access localhost from within guest do you get anything?

Comment: @EduardoDennis Yes, I get my site as expected.

Comment: so I would try to shutdown firewall and try and access from host machine with the ip within the guest, so the 192.168.2.24

Comment: @EduardoDennis Turn off firewall on host or guest...or does it matter?

Comment: on guest, well there shouldnt be any other reason why its not accessible, as I just tested your same scenario and it worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shutdown firewall, that's why it is not accessible from host. Use the IP address you get inside the guest, 192.168.2.24

Answer (score 1):

I will add my cents here. If you don't want to shutdown the firewall, you can all HTTP traffic to flow through it as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/791350/59482).

Open start menu and type `firewall with advance security` and open `Windows Firewall with Advanced Security`. In the window, select `Inbound Rules` and then double click on the `World Wide Web Service (HTTP Traffice In)` and check the Enable box. And you are done. You can access the server by putting its IP in the browser.

[image: Image showing enabling HTTP traffic in Windows firewall]